# how to execute part of code at the first time program running [ in python]

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, labview

labVIEW program sending every time X5 to rpi1 then rpi1 send ON1 or OFF1 to rpi2.
for example ON1 sending from rpi1, then if statement in rpi2 executed every time ON1 is received, now my problem is GPIO executed every time i need this part execute only at first time ON1 is received.

```
#rpi1   
 while True:
            ready_socks,_,_= select.select(socks, [],[])
            for server in ready_socks:
                cmnd, addr = server.recvfrom(1024)
                print(cmnd)
        #print(D)
        if 'X5' in str(cmnd):
                if(GPIO.input(23)==True):
                    bytes = "ON1"
                    sock.sendto(bytes,('192.168.1.22',5007))
                    data, address = so.recvfrom(1024)
                    print(data)

                if(GPIO.input(23)==False):
                    bytes = "OFF1"
                    sock.sendto(bytes,('192.168.1.22',5007))
                    data, address = so.recvfrom(1024)
                    print(data)
```

the code for rpi 2 :

```
 #rpi 2
    while True:
        ready_socks,_,_= select.select(socks, [], [])
        for sock in ready_socks:
            data,addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
            print "recived message:", data
            if 'ON1' in str(data):
               print"empty of water run the pump"
               bytes = "succeeded 1"
               sock1.sendto(bytes,('192.168.1.27',6007))
               GPIO.output(16,1)
                   time.sleep(0.1)
               GPIO.output(16,0)
               GPIO.output(18,1)

        elif 'OFF1' in str(data):
                   print "full of water"
                   bytes = "succeeded 2"
                   sock1.sendto(bytes,('192.168.1.27',6007))
                   GPIO.output(18,0)
                   time.sleep(0.1)
                   GPIO.output(18,1)
                   GPIO.output(16,0)
```

[image: Code]

Comment: Please add your (relevant) code directly to the quesiton, don't link it as an image.

Comment: @CodeF0x  i did it

please help me if you know that

Comment: @rabia use this text: [![Description][1]][1]  ... I'll edit your question to do it.